# Why does my Google Benchmark result depend on the order of execution?

Tags: c++, google-benchmark

I am trying to benchmark the potential performance increase of `emplace_back` vs. `push_back` using Google Benchmark:

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

static void BM_pushback(benchmark::State& state) {

    for(auto _ : state) {
        vector<string> data;
        for(int i=0;i<10000000;++i)
            data.push_back("A long string to avoid sbo"); 
    }
}

static void BM_emplaceback(benchmark::State& state) {

    for(auto _ : state) {
        vector<string> data;
        for(int i=0;i<10000000;++i)
            data.emplace_back("A long string to avoid sbo");
    }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_pushback)->UseRealTime();
BENCHMARK(BM_emplaceback)->UseRealTime();

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Using `g++` with `-O3` I get:

```
Running ./benchmark
Run on (8 X 4200 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x4)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x4)
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x4)
  L3 Unified 8192 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 0.60, 0.48, 0.53
***WARNING*** CPU scaling is enabled, the benchmark real time measurements may be noisy and will incur extra overhead.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                         Time             CPU   Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_pushback/real_time     886383300 ns    886276679 ns            1
BM_emplaceback/real_time  698194513 ns    698159138 ns            1
```

If I, however, change the order of execution, that is

```
BENCHMARK(BM_emplaceback)->UseRealTime();
BENCHMARK(BM_pushback)->UseRealTime();
```

I receive opposite timings:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                         Time             CPU   Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_emplaceback/real_time  863837627 ns    863814885 ns            1
BM_pushback/real_time     765406073 ns    765407578 ns            1
```

Can someone explain this behavior? I think, this might have something to do with caching but what exactly is going on here? Just as a note: What seems to help is to reduce the benchmarking size, i.e. adding only `10000` instead of `10000000` `string`s to my `vector` (which leads to more cycles being performed by the library).

Comment: On `-O3`, your two inner loops will most likely be optimized to the point where they produce the same assembly, since the data you're adding is compile-time constant. Also the resulting vector is unused, so it may get optimized away entirely, `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` could help with that.

Comment: You are almost certainly seeing the effect of malloc caching allocations. Try calling ```malloc_trim(0)``` from ```<malloc.h>``` in between benchmarks

Comment: @Homer512 I tried your solution and I added a call to  `malloc_trim(0)` at the beginning of the second function to be called, leading to almost identical run times. Thanks a lot for the great suggestion!

Comment: @perivesta No they won't. If you find a compiler that is sufficiently magical to perform these optimizations, let me know. But since the string constructor is not a fully inlined function, compilers are not able to do the kind of optimization that you propose. Feel free to check with Godbolt. https://godbolt.org/z/PKTzEc1YG

Comment: @perivesta The optimization does actually work with ```std::unique_ptr<int[]>``` but even ```std::vector<int>``` with ```reserve(n)``` is too complicated for compilers